# Issues in Posting photo on wall using API integration of Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, api, integration

I have integrated Facebook API in an android application. Purpose of my main application is shooting a image from camera and storing in SD card. Through integration of Facebook API i am posting photo on user's wall with proper authentication. Problem, what i am facing is very dramatic.Sometimes i am able to post photo on user's wall successfully, and sometimes my application has stopped with notification "Unfortunately XXXXXXXX has stopped working". ratio of failure is 1/5 .Please help me as soon as possible
Code is here

```
public class FbshareScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    public  Button                  _share;
private Button                  _decline;
int check;

public static final String APP_ID ="433644253229338";

private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};
private com.android.fb.Facebook facebook;
private String path = ProjectUtil.createSdCardDirectory("/Camera/Photo");

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebookshare);

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    _decline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    _share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/image.png",options);

    ImageView storedphoto= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storedphoto);
    storedphoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    _decline.setOnClickListener(this);
    _share.setOnClickListener(this);

    facebook.setAccessExpires(5000);
}  

    private void logoutFromFacebook() 
    {
      AsyncFacebookRunner    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
         mAsyncRunner.logout(FbshareScreen.this, new RequestListener() 
         {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
                {
                    Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) 
                    {
                        // User successfully Logged out
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                }
            });

    }   


    public void loginAndPostToWall()
    {
         facebook.authorize(this,PERMISSIONS,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new LoginDialogListener());
         //facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener() {}); 
    }
    String  response;
    public void postToWall(String message)
    { 

        try {
            addVango(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagepicker),BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ProjectUtil.createSdCardDirectory("/Camera/Photo")+"/image.png"));

            byte[] data = null;
            try
            {

                FileInputStream fis =  new FileInputStream(ProjectUtil.createSdCardDirectory("/Camera/Photo")+"/image.png");
                Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, baos);
                data = baos.toByteArray(); 
                }catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FbshareScreen.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                response=facebook.request("me");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();       
                parameters.putString("message", message);   
                parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
                 AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);   
                 mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", parameters, "POST", new mRequestListener(), null);

                 Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                 if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) 
                 {   
                    Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                    Toast.makeText(FbshareScreen.this,"Blank response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    check=1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     check=2;


                     Intent FBshare_Home =  new Intent(FbshareScreen.this,FacebookFeedback.class);
                     startActivity(FBshare_Home);
                     File file= new File(path+"/image.png");
                     file.delete();
                     finish();

                 }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
    class LoginDialogListener implements com.android.fb.Facebook.DialogListener
    {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            new MailSendingTask().execute((Void[])null);


                //postToWall("");

        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
        {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            File f= new File("/mnt/sdcard/Camera/Photo/image.png");
            if(f.canRead())
            {
                f.delete();
            }
            Intent in=new Intent (FbshareScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            File f= new File("/mnt/sdcard/Camera/Photo/image.png");
            if(f.canRead())
            {
                f.delete();
            }
            Intent in=new Intent (FbshareScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            File f= new File("/mnt/sdcard/Camera/Photo/image.png");
            if(f.canRead())
            {
                f.delete();
            }
            Intent in=new Intent (FbshareScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
    }
    class WallPostDialogListener implements com.android.fb.Facebook.DialogListener {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            logoutFromFacebook();
                if (response != null)
                {
                 showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");

            } else {
                showToast("Wall post cancelled!");   
            }
            finish();

        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Wall post cancelled!");
            finish();
        }
    }
    private void showToast(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public class mRequestListener implements RequestListener{

        private static final String TAG = "I am Tag";

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onMalformedURLException *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onIOException *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onFileNotFoundException *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onFacebookError *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onComplete *******************");
        }

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        if(view == _share)
        {
            if(!ProjectUtil.haveNetworkConnection(FbshareScreen.this)){
                Toast.makeText(FbshareScreen.this,"Unable to connect at this time please check your network connection and try again.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            new FacebookSendingTask().execute((Void[])null);

            loginAndPostToWall(); 


        }else if(view == _decline){
            File file= new File(path+"/image.png");
            file.delete();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo Deleted \nClick Another Photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            finish();
        }

    }
public Bitmap   addVango(Bitmap c, Bitmap s)
{
    Bitmap cs = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) 
    { 
      width = c.getWidth();   
      height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
    } else { 
      width = s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
    } 


    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth()-s.getWidth()-75, c.getHeight()-s.getHeight()-155, null);



    OutputStream os = null; 
    try { 
      os = new FileOutputStream(ProjectUtil.createSdCardDirectory("/Camera/Photo")+"/image.png"); 
      cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); 
    } catch(IOException e) 
    { 
      Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e); 
      Toast.makeText(FbshareScreen.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return cs; 
}


 public class MailSendingTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public  Looper mLooper;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    FbshareScreen.this,

                    "Doing Processing", // title
                    "Posting Photo", // message
                    true // indeterminate
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //if(haveNetworkConnection())

            try
            {
                postToWall("");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Log.e("Exception", exception.toString());
                check=1;
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            this.progressDialog.cancel();
            if(check==1)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wall Post Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(check==2)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Posted To your Wall", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        }

    }

 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
            File file= new File(path+"/image.png");
            if(file.canRead())
            {
            file.delete();

            Intent in=new Intent(FbshareScreen.this,FacebookFeedback.class);
            in.putExtra("value", "1");
            startActivity(in);             
            return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }




 public class FacebookSendingTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public  Looper mLooper;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    FbshareScreen.this,

                    "Connecting To Facebook", // title
                    "Wait for a Moment", // message
                    true 
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



            try {
                facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            this.progressDialog.cancel();
    }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is  arising because your application is exceeding cache limit of your android device.The heap size of  android device is causing this memory exception. Please upgrade memory or use higher end devices.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you are getting `outofmemoryerror` while posting photos. This is very tricky to handle at run time the allocation/deallocation of images in Android because it takes too much heap. May be you are getting problem because of your device ..I would suggest you to please upgrade memory or use higher end devices

Comment: failure log

and >>> E/AndroidRuntime(2000): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError E/AndroidRuntime(2000): at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(2000): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605) E/AndroidRuntime(2000): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551) E/AndroidRuntime(2000): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437) E/AndroidRuntime(2000): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524) E/AndroidRuntime(2000): at com.vangocam.FbshareScreen.postToWall(FbshareScreen.java:123) –